# Array output in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I'm ever so green with PHP so here's what i'm trying to do. I have an array

```
$companyStates = array("AR","TX","LA","OK","GA","NC","SC");
```

Just a list of US states.I need to do two simple things with this array: 1) print the values of the array in this format: ARTXLAOKGANCSC no spaces just values for use with some javascript i'm using. 2) Then, add to a string variable the number 100 for each item in the array, separated by commas. End result I need two variables with values ARTXLAOKGANCSC and 100,100,100,100,100,100,100

normally, I'd do a for in loop and push to an array and list out the values of the array, but i'm not familiar enough with php syntax to accomplish this.. thanks for the help!

Comment: FYI php has [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) instead of `for in`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but I think it should work:

```
$companyStates = array("AR","TX","LA","OK","GA","NC","SC");
$nameList = implode('',$companyStates);
$numList = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($companyStates); $i++) {
    $numList .= ',100';
}
$numList = substr($numList,1,strlen($numList));
```

Comment: Thanks. See, i'm used to javascript and actionscript and instead of count($compandStates) i'd do companyStates.length and push ',100' to an array and print the array for the other object.. i value PHP, but it's not what i was hired to do, it's just required for what i need to do at this point. thanks so much!

Comment: @RyanHollingsworth you can usually search google for this sort of stuff. "php array length" would have told you that. PHP may not be your job, but your project isn't anybody else's job either. Asking for help is different than asking for somebody to do it for you.

Comment: Oh i'm not looking for quick fix.. this is a very simple syntax translation, which is less verbose than language definition. I've spent the past several minutes reading on the syntax terms posted by people here. substr, count, already been in implode and explode. but yes.. it's impossible to master every language out there, and inappropriate to ask you to do my job for me.. and honestly.. if you look at what i asked compared to the task it's related to .. no one would think that ;)

Answer (score 1):

1.

```
<?php

echo implode('', $companyStates);
```

2.

```
<?php

echo implode(',', array_fill(0, count($companyStates), 100));
```

Answer (score 1):

The first is very simple: just use [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) with no "glue":

```
echo implode($companyStates);
```

The second is slightly more complex. I'd use `implode` again, combined with [`array_fill`](http://php.net/array_fill):

```
echo implode(',', array_fill(0, count($companyStates), '100'));
```

This makes an array of the same length as `$companyStates` where all the elements are the string `100`, then collapses them with a `,` between each argument.

Comment: Yup! sure is.. i'm not a php developer, I work mostly with action script and i was looking at the implode without glue and was looking to state a question without mentioning what i had reviewed to see if others who actually use PHP regularly would suggest something more efficient and professionally than i had stumbled upon. Thanks :)

Comment: @RyanHollingsworth In future, you'll get a much better response if you show what you've tried...

Comment: i guess you're right. it will simply 'taint the water' as they say and keep from getting truly objective and fresh points of view.. but not always.. That's the only reason i go to this site for help.. when i've explored every thing i can think of.. and tried everything i can think of to google. thanks!